# Ruby on Rails temporary instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use an instance variable throughout a class's methods. Unfortunately, the methods are all class (not instance) methods, so the classic `@my_data ||= [1,2,3]` doesn't work, since every call to the class's class-methods will reuse the same data forever:

```rb
class MyThing
  class << self

    def do_something
      do_something_else
    end

    private

    def my_data
      @my_data ||= Time.now
    end

    def do_something_else
      puts my_data
    end
  end
end

MyThing.do_something # puts the current time
MyThing.do_something # puts the same time as above (not what I want)
```

One way around it is to declare the variable, then set it to nil at the end of the method like this:

```rb
class MyThing
  class << self

    def do_something
      @my_data = my_data
      do_something_else
      @my_data = nil
    end

    private

    def my_data
      Time.now
    end

    def do_something_else
      puts @my_data || my_data
    end
  end
end

MyThing.do_something # puts the current time
MyThing.do_something # puts the new current time (yay)
```

However, setting the data and destroying it at the start and end of the method seems messy.

**Is there a cleaner way to say "set (@my_data = Time.now) until the end of this method"?**

Comment: This way, there's not much need for cleanup. If you remove `@my_data = nil`, it will still work correctly.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the methods are all class (not instance) methods" - what I like to do in such cases is make all other methods instance methods. Then the root class method will simply create a new instance of the class and the rest "just works".

Answer (score 0):

It's soluiton, if I understand you correctly.

```rb
class MyThing
  class << self

    def do_something
      do_something_else
    end

    private

    def my_data
      @my_data = Time.now
    end

    def do_something_else
      puts my_data
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No, I want to call `MyThing.do_something` and have it print Time.now both times. This code will print the first `Time.now` result twice.

Comment: My solution works exactly the same as your second example. What's wrong?

Comment: Ah sorry I got it mixed up—the problem with your solution is that there is no memoization. If it were complex logic instead of `Time.now` then it would be run every time `my_data` is called, it would never be saved for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

The name says it all "instance variable" is available as long as the instance lives. In your case that instance is the `MyThing` class, meaning it doesn't reset automatically. Classes stay loaded as long as your program runs, so it will never reset.

The simplest solution for the given scenario is to use method arguments.

```
class MyThing
  class << self
    def do_something
      do_something_else(my_data)
    end

    private

    def do_something_else(my_data)
      puts my_data || Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

The other option you already discovered, that is, setting an instance variable and then resetting it.

---

Another alternative is moving the thing your doing into an class instance. The disadvantage here is that this solution produces more overhead code. However it does keep the `MyThing` class cleaner, since you can move helper methods into this new class.

```
class MyThing
  class DataObject
    attr_reader :data

    def initialize(data)
      @data = data || Time.now
    end

    def do_something_else
      puts data
    end
  end

  class << self
    def do_something
      DataObject.new(my_data).do_something_else
    end
  end
end
```

If possible you could also create a `MyThing` instance instead of an `DataObject` instance, but I assumed the `MyThing` class already has another purpose.